# Angular form validation fails after removing `is-invalid` class from input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have prepared on StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iuif7k?file=src/app/app.component.ts) a very simple app with form containing one input field and one submit button. The code contains classic validation for the required username field in `validation-form.component.html`. The input field contains the dynamic class initialization `[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f['username'].errors }"`.
Validation (after pressing `Submit` button) is working fine (displaying `Username is required` - when input field is left empty) until I remove from input field the above class `[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f['username'].errors }"`. After removing that class, validation does not display an error anymore when I press submit button.
Is this by design or it is a genuine bug in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error element is there even when you remove `ngClass`, It just doesn't display because the default class you have `.invalid-feedback` has `display: none`

Remove `.invalid-feedback` class and you will see it working with or without `ngClass`

It works with `ngClass` because when you submit without entering the value `ngClass` gets satisfied and `is-invalid` class gets added, and this class has `display:block` which overrides `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular. `is-invalid` is a Bootstrap CSS class in which you control by adding it to a particular element using a condition; in your case the condition is `submitted && f['username'].errors`.

This `is-invalid` is usually used to wrap the error message using `*ngIf` and also have the CSS error attributes such as the red border color on `input` etc...

So when you remove it, the styling won't be visible.

Proper "`Angular`" validation is required within the `onSubmit` method like this

```
onSubmit(value: any) {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (!this.myForm.valid) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why class of `input` element affects the next `div` element (with the `*ngIf` attribute) that is independent of `input` element.